# Insertar un registro desde un query construido en una cadena de texto

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas tardes, estoy tratando de insertar registros desde un Cursor hacia una tabla en SQL pero construyendo la sentencia Insert en una variable de tipo texto.

Dentro de los valores tengo un campo de tipo entero, varios textos y una fecha, al parecer estoy con algunas complicaciones en el armado, de repente me pueden dar una luz al respecto.

Lo que quiero construir es algo parecido a esto:

```
set @queryTexto = 'Insert into <<tabla>> (<<lista de campos>>) 
    Values (@campoNumerico, @campo1, @campo2, @campo3, ''ACT'', @campoFecha)'
exec @queryTexto
```

He visto en algunos ejemplos que hay que hacer conversión de valores, también he visto el uso del `CHAR(39)`.
¿Qué recomendaciones me podrian dar?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Juan Bienvenido a SO en Español, podrias indicar que complicaciones has tenido, asi es mas facil que podamos ayudar a resolver tu problema :)

Comment: Hola, gracias por la bienvenida, no tanto son complicaciones, sino lo que quería ver cual sería la mejor forma de hacer este proceso. He tenido que ir descartando con conversiones de datos, primero para la fecha, luego para el valor entero, he usado Convert para ambos casos. Luego tuve que agregarle char(39) a cada lado de cada campo porque al parecer hay que encerrarlos entre comillas, para que todo se concatene como una sola cadena. Ya logré resolver los problemas y ya funciona correctamente pero siempre es bueno ver si hay mejores caminos. Saludos.

Comment: Lo mejor sería que indicaras el tipo de dato de cada variable

Comment: el primer dato es **int** los siguientes son **varchar** y el último es un @@getdate() para obtener la fecha actual del sistema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La mejor forma de hacerlo sería que al ejecutar la consulta de texto le pasarás los parámetros tipados. Esto lo puedes hacer usando el procedimiento almacenado [`sp_executesql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms188001(v=sql.120).aspx) *(este mismo procedimiento lo suelen usar las capas de acceso a datos como ADO.NET cuando lanzan consultas parametrizadas)*

El uso de este procedimiento para tu consulta de inserción sería así:

```
declare @queryTexto nvarchar(MAX), @Now datetime

set @queryTexto = 'insert into TestDynamicInsert 
    (IntegerField, DateField, StringField) 
    values (@p1, @p2, @p3)'

SET @Now = getdate()

exec sp_executesql @queryTexto, N'@p1 int,@p2 datetime,@p3 varchar(128)',
     @p1=1, @p2=@Now, @p3='Texto de prueba'
```

La función `getdate()` para obtener la fecha actual no funciona ejecutándola en el la llamada al procedimiento almacenado por lo que hay que guardarla en una variable

*Este código lo he comprobado en **SQL Server 2014**, supongo que también funcionará en versiones anteriores*

Comment: Hola, retomando el caso, hice las pruebas como me comentas en tu respuesta pero no he logrado salir adelante, en mi caso tengo 10 campos, aunque sé que eso no debería ser problema, debería funcionar igual con 1 o con 100 valores pero no he tenido suerte.
Ni bien intentaba ejecutar el proceso me daba un error en la primera linea, indicando que el procedimiento almacenado necesitaba parametros que no se le estaban haciendo llegar.
He vuelto a la primera versión de mi programa pero ahora tengo otro tipo de error, eso lo estoy preguntando en otra pregunta.
Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Hola @JuanManuelPalacios, te he respondido en tu otra pregunta, poniéndote como se haría la consulta usando esta técnica. Saludos

Comment: Es cierto esa manera por mi parte tambn la probe sin resultados efectivos