# ¿Por qué obtengo que mi sentencia SQL no es un identificador válido?

Tags: sql, tsql

Estoy armando una instrucción de `INSERT` en el SQL con valores almacenados en variables que vienen de un `CURSOR` al que voy recorriendo. A la hora de ejecutar la instrucción `INSERT` estoy obteniendo un error de identificador inválido.

El código que estoy trabajando es el siguiente y está dentro de un ciclo repetitivo que obtiene datos de un cursor:

```sql
IF (@Estado = 'V')
    SET @NuevoEstado = 'ACT'
ELSE
    SET @NuevoEstado = 'ANU'

SET @ClienteId = (
        SELECT ClienteId
        FROM QueryClientesDescriptivo
        WHERE CodigoContribuyente = @RUC
            AND Estado = 'ACT'
        )
SET @MovimientoInventarioId = @MovimientoInventarioId + 1
SET @Query = 'INSERT INTO [COMPU90].[SIV3].[dbo].MovimientosInventario (CompaniaId, MovimientoInventarioId, TipoMovimientoInventarioId, Fecha, Glosa, AlmacenId, PersonaId, Estado, OrigenId, Migracion) ' + 'VALUES (' + CHAR(39) + '10043' + CHAR(39) + ',' + CHAR(39) + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @MovimientoInventarioId) + CHAR(39) + ',' + CHAR(39) + 'SVEN' + CHAR(39) + ',' + CHAR(39) + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Fecha, 101) + CHAR(39) + ',' + CHAR(39) + '' + CHAR(39) + ',' + CHAR(39) + '2' + CHAR(39) + ',' + CHAR(39) + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @ClienteId) + CHAR(39) + ',' + CHAR(39) + @NuevoEstado + CHAR(39) + ',' + CHAR(39) + '0' + CHAR(39) + ',' + CHAR(39) + '0' + CHAR(39) + ')'

EXEC @Query
```

El mensaje de error que obtengo es el siguiente:

> The name 'INSERT INTO [COMPU90].[SIV3].[dbo].MovimientosInventario
>   (CompaniaId, MovimientoInventarioId, TipoMovimientoInventarioId,
>   Fecha, Glosa, AlmacenId, PersonaId, Estado, OrigenId, Migracion)
>   VALUES
>   ('10043','141907','SVEN','01/04/2016','','2','253624','ANU','0','0')'
>   is not a valid identifier.

He probado cambiando el formato de la fecha, la forma en como pasar los parámetros pero ninguna forma me libera de ese error, sin embargo, al ejecutarlo directamente funciona sin darme errores.

Comment: A que variante de SQL te refieres?

Comment: Es SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Agrega paréntesis, en la línea que ejecuta el query:

```
EXEC (@query)
```

Comment: WOW, muchas gracias Elena, eso si que me resolvio el problema.
En español se les llama parentesis y al agregar ese par de caracteres ha funcionado correctamente. Como algo tan simple puede sacarte de un problema que me ha tenido como 4 horas dandole vueltas.
Nuevamente muchas gracias, me has ayudado un montón.

Comment: Es un placer, a mi me sucedió el mismo problema hace tiempo: "The name ( ) is not a valid identifier."

Comment: Que increible, muchas gracias de nuevo, ahora voy a poder seguir avanzando el proyecto y a partir de ahora voy a ponerle parentesis a todos los **EXEC** que utilice.

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero, ya llevaba algo de tiempo intentando e intentando...

Answer (score 1):

También podrías lanzar la consulta usando el procedimiento almacenado [`sp_executesql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms188001(v=sql.120).aspx) que te mencionaba en tu [otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/4373/602) pregunta

El código que utilizarías sería el siguiente (en mi ejemplo hago un bucle para insertar 10 registros):

```
/*CREATE TABLE MovimientosInventario (
    CompaniaId int, MovimientoInventarioId int, TipoMovimientoInventarioId varchar(64), Fecha datetime, 
    Glosa varchar(64), AlmacenId int, PersonaId int, Estado varchar(64), OrigenId int, Migracion bit)*/

DECLARE @Estado varchar(64), @NuevoEstado varchar(64), @Fecha datetime,
    @ClienteId int, @MovimientoInventarioId int

IF (@Estado = 'V') 
    SET @NuevoEstado = 'ACT' 
ELSE
    SET @NuevoEstado = 'ANU'

SET @ClienteId = 3
SET @MovimientoInventarioId = 0

while (@MovimientoInventarioId < 10) 
begin
    SET @MovimientoInventarioId = @MovimientoInventarioId + 1
    SET @Fecha = GETDATE()

    exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO MovimientosInventario (
            CompaniaId, MovimientoInventarioId, TipoMovimientoInventarioId, Fecha, 
            Glosa, AlmacenId, PersonaId, Estado, OrigenId, Migracion) 

        VALUES (
            @CompaniaId, @MovimientoInventarioId, @TipoMovimientoInventarioId, @Fecha, 
            @Glosa, @AlmacenId, @PersonaId, @Estado, @OrigenId, @Migracion)', 

        N'@CompaniaId int, @MovimientoInventarioId int, @TipoMovimientoInventarioId varchar(64), @Fecha datetime, 
        @Glosa varchar(64), @AlmacenId int, @PersonaId int, @Estado varchar(64), @OrigenId int, @Migracion bit', 

        @CompaniaId=10043, @MovimientoInventarioId=@MovimientoInventarioId, @TipoMovimientoInventarioId='SVEN', @Fecha=@Fecha, 
        @Glosa='', @AlmacenId=2, @PersonaId=@ClienteId, @Estado=@NuevoEstado, @OrigenId=0, @Migracion=0

end
```

La ventaja de hacerlo así es que el código es mucho mas limpio y manteniente y que los parámetros están tipados.

Y probablemente mas óptimo porque, al ser una consulta parametrizada, se tendrá un único plan de ejecución

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, justamente eso fue lo que intenté hacer al principio, traté de armar la consulta con ese formato utilizando los valores obtenidos desde el cursor pero no me resultaba, por eso fue que regresé a la otra forma, igual voy a probar tu alternativa. Si es como bien dices, que es mucho más óptima y limpia de repente sea la forma mas adecuada. Nuevamente muchas gracias.